# I want to search a txt file for a specific word and print the whole line

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is currently:

```
admin_username_choice = input("Enter the user's username: ")
with open("data.txt") as f:
    line = f.read().split()
for line in f:
    if admin_username_choice in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print("Incorrect information")
```

but this prints out - for line in f:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

`with` closes the file thus making it not accessible by the rest of the code. You might want to check your indentation.

```
admin_username_choice = input("Enter the user's username: ")
with open("data.txt") as f:
    line = f.read().split()
    if admin_username_choice in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print("Incorrect information")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
admin_username_choice = input("Enter the user's username: ")
lines='' #just to initialize "lines" out of the with statement 
with open("data.txt") as f:
    lines = f.read().split()
#"f" becomes "lines" here. You will already have closed "f" at this point
for line in lines:
    if admin_username_choice in line:
        print(line)
    else:
        print("Incorrect information")
```

Comment: usually it's appropriate to add a bit of a description to your code to help the asker understand why you did what you did

Comment: That's true. Lemme edit

Comment: `lines` doesn't need to be initialized (with statements don't push or pop a stack frame) and will be a list anyway as the result of `.split()` returns a list.

Comment: @Aaron yea i couldn't remember for sure if it needed it or not. I tend to use that in my code a lot, unless it's going to happen so much that it affects performance.

Comment: Ok idk why but this doesn't work

Comment: initialization is useful for things like numpy arrays (where many numpy functions support passing a writeback variable to prevent multiple copies in memory at once) and instances where a value may need to be referenced before the location it would otherwise be written to.

Comment: @Kingline5858 what's the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

Your indent blocks are off. The with statement closes the file when you go to the for block. This code should do what you want.

```
admin_username_choice = input("Enter the user's username: ")
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if admin_username_choice in line.split():
            print(line)
        else:
            print("Incorrect information")
```